# Bootstrapping in Bayesian Statistics

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap

I am reading the book Data Analysis: A Bayesian Tutorial. The book mentions it would be wrong to bootstrap a single data element and use the posterior pdf as the prior. I understand it would be wrong to do this but can you show me either mathematically or intuitively why this bootstrap idea is folly.

Comment: Of interest: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176345338

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "single data element".  If you mean use $ p (\theta|y_1) $ as a prior for processing $ y_2,\dots,y_n $ then what you describe is perfectly reasonable to do.

Comment: Single data element means y1 only. And that y1 is used repeatedly to update the posterior.

Comment: From your description, it is hard to tell what the author means. Can you provide a page number for the second edition of the book where this bootstrapping comment is made?